# How to pass image from one page to another where image is fetched from url

Tags: android, json

I need to pass image fetched from url into another activity page. I'm able to do so foe textviews. But i got stuck how to pass image from one page to another in android. dynamically through url.
can anyone give some suggestions regarding this.

Comment: save image in folder for first time and just pass path to second page........ or use lazyloading library\

Answer (score 1):

1.First Way

`Bitmap` implements `Parcelable`

For Sent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, BActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("image", bitmap);
```

and Retrieve :

`Intent intent = getIntent();`
   `Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("image");`

2.Second Way

//Convert to byte array for sent

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

Intent in1 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
in1.putExtra("image",byteArray);
```

Then Retrieve in another activity:

```
byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Comment: i tried ur first way of sending image.. the code is working without any issues, but i'm unable to send and receive the images.                                do we need to initialize the bitmap to null

Comment: in the second way , what is "bmp" . what object is this. I'm getting issues in that object ---> "bmp"

Comment: please help me to get through this.. I'm learning these concepts newly and tried hard to get through it.. pls help

Comment: what issue are you facing?

Comment: Thanks a lot....my issue solved with ur first way of code... just added @lines before it and i'm able to pass image from one activity to another using intents.                                                                                                  1st activity:       imageview.buildDrawingCache();
              Bitmap bitmap = imageview.getDrawingCache();

           
              intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);

Comment: 2nd activity:           Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
 
      ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
      view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: @NadhinideviBalakrishnan.G Great ,if you got solution from this answer,should accept it

Answer (score 0):

By using [intent](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html) you can pass image url. from there you have to display that. You can not pass Image.

**send data using intent**

```
Intent openNewActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
openNewActivity.putExtra("image", "www.fb.com/profilepic.png");
    startActivity(openNewActivity);
```

get data from your Activity2.class file
write this code in your onCreate method

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String image;

if (extras != null) {
    image = extras.getString("image");
    // and get whatever type user account id is
}
```

now set image url on Image.

Comment: i tried using put extra method. its not working for me. how to get and sent (to another activity page)  image url using intents

Comment: i shared link on intent click it and open